# Coresphere console bundle 301 error

Tags: symfony, console, hosting, shared

I'm trying to deploy a symfony project, but something is wrong with the console (I'm on a shared hosting).
It worked just fine on localhost, but on the server, it seems to be looping, which I'm having trouble debugging, since I'm not really sure why this is happening..

Edit : Prior to uploading, I changed my DB parameters, renamed the web folder according to the name used by my host, allowed my IP in app_dev, and made sure everything worked fine under app.php on localhost. Once uploaded, config.php did not have any recommendations.

Can anyone please help?
Thanks

[Here's a screenshot of firebug when I try to run the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCw9J.png)

Comment: Impossible to help with only "_something is wrong with the console_" Please read [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly adding more info about the steps followed to deploy your project.

Comment: Not just "something is wrong", I did put that screenshot too :) Prior to uploading, I changed my DB parameters, renamed the web folder according to the name used by my host, allowed my IP in app_dev, and made sure everything worked fine under app.php on localhost. Once uploaded, config.php did not have any recommendations.